# Exception Handling in Haskell no parse

Tags: haskell

So I have a file where the first line has the format `([String], [(Int, Int)], [(Int, Int)], Int)` and the rest of the lines have the format `[((Int, Int), (Int, Int), String)]`. I managed to get the the input and parse it with the following function:

```
someFunction :: String -> IO (String)
someFunction fileName = do
    handle <- openFile fileName ReadMode
    contents <- hGetLine handle
    let firstLine = read contents :: ([String], [(Int, Int)], [(Int, Int)], Int)
    restOfLines <- map read <$> lines <$> hGetContents handle :: IO [((Int, Int), (Int, Int), String)]
    ...
```

The thing is, that I want to print a custom error if the file has the wrong format. So if something is missing or what not, it should only print "some error". Otherwise, the lines have to be parsed so I can do some other things with the content. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Sounds like you want to look at `readMaybe` or `readEither`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to detect whether a `Read` parser failed is to use `readMaybe`. E.g. in GHCi:

```
> import Text.Read (readMaybe)

> :t readMaybe
readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a    -- Defined in ‘Text.Read’

> readMaybe "1" :: Maybe Int
Just 1

> readMaybe ":(" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
```

You can pattern-match on the result of `readMaybe` with `case` like any other use of `Maybe`:

```
case readMaybe input of
  Just parsed -> …  -- Use parsed value
  Nothing -> …      -- Report error
```

This can only report a generic failure; for more complex parsing and validation, you should use a proper parsing library. One included with `base` is `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`:

```
import Control.Applicative (some)
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP (ReadP)
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP as ReadP

-- Parse one or more digits.
number :: ReadP Int
number = read <$> some (ReadP.satisfy isDigit)
```

These parsers can be executed on some input with `readP_to_S`; by default they enumerate all possible parses, which you can constrain with functions like `eof` (require complete input) or `<++` (biased choice).

```
> import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP (readP_to_S)

> readP_to_S number "123"
[(1,"23"),(12,"3"),(123,"")]

> readP_to_S (number <* ReadP.eof) "123"
[(123,"")]
```

You can pattern-match on the resulting list to validate, for example, that there’s only one result and extract what you want or report the error. Another popular choice of parsing library is the `megaparsec` package, which can additionally provide nice custom error messages with source locations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Btw, could you give some examples of non-generic failures that it can not report?

Comment: @bobthesnob: Sure, `readMaybe` only tells you *whether* parsing succeeded or failed, not *why* (e.g. a missing bracket) or *where* (what line/column). A `ReadP` parser returns the possible parses and leftover input, which you can use to construct a more helpful message than just “invalid format”. Parsing packages like Megaparsec do that automatically: when a parser fails, it will return a message like a typical compiler error, like “unexpected end of input; expected closing bracket or comma” with a location, and it offers a way to add labels to your parsers which it will use in those messages.

Comment: @bobthesnob: `Read` & `Show` are meant for debugging. Like `repr` in Python, `show` is supposed to return a string of Haskell code for a whole “raw” value, which can just be copied & pasted into GHCi or a source file to reconstruct the same value. In a “real” program, it’s quite beneficial to use proper parsing libraries instead of `Read`; for example, `read` will stop working on old files if you change the data type at all, even just reordering/renaming fields in a record! Likewise, pretty-printing libraries like `prettyprinter` are much better at formatting human-readable text than `Show`.